# Problem with switching words in a sentence

Tags: arrays, c, string

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAKS_RIJECI 100
#define MAKS_DUZINA_RIJECI 50

char *ispremjestaj(char recenica[], int pozicije[], int brojPozicije) {
    static char rezultat[MAKS_DUZINA_RIJECI * MAKS_RIJECI];
    char *rijeci[MAKS_RIJECI];
    int brojac = 0;
    char *token = strtok(recenica, " ");
    while (token != NULL && brojac < MAKS_RIJECI) {
        rijeci[brojac++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < brojPozicije; i++) {
        int pozicija = pozicije[i] - 1;
        if (pozicija >= 0 && pozicija < brojac) {
            char *temp = rijeci[pozicija];
            for (int j = pozicija; j > 0; j--) {
                rijeci[j] = rijeci[j - 1];
            }
            rijeci[0] = temp;
        }
    }
    strcpy(rezultat, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < brojac; i++) {
        strcat(rezultat, rijeci[i]);
        strcat(rezultat, " ");
    }
    rezultat[strlen(rezultat) - 1] = '\0';
    return rezultat;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

When there is a like a big gap in between words or there is a space at the end of a sentence it removes it, I tried to fix that just by adding another `if` statement where if the end of the main sentence ends with a space then the final sentence should too but it didn't work. And there is also a bug where for this example this happens,

Result: Incorrect result
Test code:

This below is just the test inputs in `main`:

```
char text[] = "Introduction to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science";
int array[] = { 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 };
printf("'%s'\n", ispremjestaj(text, array, 20));
printf("'%s'", ispremjestaj(text, array, 21));
```

Input/output of the program:

**Expected output(s):**

```
'Introduction to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science'
'to Introduction programming is a new name for Basics of computer science'
```

**My program printed:**

```
'Introduction to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science'
'Introduction'
```

Execution time (rounded): 0 seconds

**EDIT:** **Here is my code modified by chqrlie's code.**

But can this be done just by modifing the input sentence (`recenica`) and not using another string (`rezultat`)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAKS_RIJECI 100

char *ispremjestaj(char recenica[], const int pozicije[], int brojPozicije) {
    const char *rijeci[MAKS_RIJECI];
    size_t duzine[MAKS_RIJECI];
    int brojac = 0;
    const char *p = recenica;
    for (brojac = 0; brojac < MAKS_RIJECI; brojac++) {
        p += strspn(p, " "); 
        if (*p == '\0')
            break;
        rijeci[brojac] = p;
        duzine[brojac] = strcspn(p, " ");
        p += duzine[brojac];
    }
    for(int i =0;i<brojPozicije;i++){
        int pozicija=pozicije[i]-1;
        if(pozicija>=0 && pozicija<brojac){
            const char *temp=rijeci[pozicija];
            int duzina=duzine[pozicija];
            for(int j=pozicija;j-- >0;){
                rijeci[j+1]=rijeci[j];
                duzine[j+1]=duzine[j];
            }
            rijeci[0]=temp;
            duzine[0]=duzina;
        }
    }
    char rezultat[100];
        char *q=rezultat;
        
        for(int i=0;i<brojac;i++){
            memcpy(q, rijeci[i], duzine[i]);
            q+=duzine[i];
            *q++=' ';}
            if(q>rezultat)
            --q;
            if(recenica [strlen(recenica)-1]==' ')
            *q++=' ';
            *q='\0';   

    
     strcpy(recenica, rezultat);

    return recenica;
    
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I reformatted the code for clarity, but I am afraid the foreign variable names still make it very difficult to analyze the code.  You should consider using English for code and comments to get help from a wider audience.

Comment: What is your programme supposed to do? Can you switch words that are different lengths? I think this will require `memmove` between the two?

Comment: @Neil: the result is constructed in a local `static` array and returned to the caller via a pointer.  This is sloppy but should work for reasonably short strings.

Comment: `strtok` is destructive to the input, and is probably the wrong tool for the job (unless you are going to restore the spaces afterwards.) Perhaps a more useful function is [strpbrk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/functions/strpbrk.html). Still not sure what `array` is.

Comment: @eminbihh: indeed `strtok` is the wrong tool... meet the usual suspects: `strtok`, `strncpy`, `feof`, `gets`... and also beware of `realloc` and `sprintf`.

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post, don't change your existing post. Changing an answered question creates confusion. Answering this changed question would create even more confusion, so people will not answer a changed question.

Comment: And yes, you can modify the input sentence without copying, but it's still going to be O(n) time, because differing lengths require a shifting of all letters between the two words (hence `memmove`). Suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is incorrect because the `ispremjestaj` function modifies its argument string, namely it breaks it into tokens using `strtok()`.  The second call gets a sentence that has just the first word as the space has been replaced with a null byte.

It is unclear whether you should modify the argument string or the array of positions or if you should allocate space for the result string to avoid overwriting the previous result.  From the discussion, it seems returning the address of a `static` array is the expected behavior that is both compatible with preserving the argument string and not causing memory leaks, but this is bad practice and clarification would be helpful.

Instead of `strtok()`, you can use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` from the C library that use the same separator string and measure the number of characters from the string that match (resp. don't match) one of the separators.

It is unclear how this function should handle initial, multiple and trailing spaces, so I removed initial and trailing spaces and replaced sequences of spaces with a single one (as you did).

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 100
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 50

char *reorder(const char *sentence, const int positions[], int number_of_positions) {
    const char *words[MAX_WORDS];
    size_t lengths[MAX_WORDS];
    int counter = 0;
    const char *p = sentence;
    for (counter = 0; counter < MAX_WORDS; counter++) {
        p += strspn(p, " ");  /* skip blanks */
        if (*p == '\0')
            break;
        words[counter] = p;
        lengths[counter] = strcspn(p, " ");
        p += lengths[counter];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_positions; i++) {
        int position = positions[i] - 1;
        if (position >= 0 && position < counter) {
            const char *word = words[position];
            size_t length = lengths[position];
            for (int j = position; j-- > 0;) {
                words[j + 1] = words[j];
                lengths[j + 1] = lengths[j];
            }
            words[0] = word;
            lengths[0] = length;
        }
    }
    char result[MAX_WORDS * MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 2];
    char *q = result;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        memcpy(q, words[i], lengths[i]);
        q += lengths[i];
        *q++ = ' ';
    }
    if (q > result)
        --q;
    *q = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char text[] = "Introduction to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science";
    int array[] = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
    printf("'%s'\n", reorder(text, array, 20));
    printf("'%s'\n", reorder(text, array, 21));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but can we somehow free the allocated memory before the int main?

Comment: like in the function itself because i modified it and it will output the desired output but it doest pass cuz we dont free the allocated memory

Comment: @eminbihh: It is unclear whether you can or should modify the argument string or the array of positions or if you should allocate space for the result string to avoid overwriting the previous result.  From the discussion, it seems returning the address of a `static` array is the expected behavior that is both compatible with preserving the argument string and not causing memory leaks, but this is bad practice and clarification would be helpful.  This modified version no longer leaks memory but still might not handle spacing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is both incomplete and complicated. As reported in the comments, `strtok()` regards consecutive *delimiters* as a single instance making preservation of SP characters impossible.

Following the KISS principle, the following may be what you're looking for. The logic is simple and easy to understand, and it is flexible. It's unclear if you want to swap only the first two *words* (with the SPs that follow those words), or swap pairs of words found in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    char *cp = "  Introduction    to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science  ";
    char buf[ 64 ]; // big enough for one word and its trailing whitespace

    printf( "'%s'\n'", cp ); // initial string + lead single quote

    while( *cp == ' ' ) putchar( *cp++ ); // leading SPs

    // while( *cp )
    {
        int n = 0;
        while( *cp && *cp != ' ' ) buf[n++] = *cp++; // direct 1st word to buffer
        while(        *cp == ' ' ) buf[n++] = *cp++; // with its suffix SPs

        while( *cp && *cp != ' ' ) putchar( *cp++ ); // direct 2nd word to output
        while(        *cp == ' ' ) putchar( *cp++ ); // with its suffix SPs

        for( int i = 0; i < n; ) putchar( buf[i++] ); // output 1st word + its suffix SPs
    }

    while( *cp ) putchar( *cp++ ); // output rest of the string

    printf( "'\n" ); // trailing single quote

    return 0;
}
```

Result from shown code:

```
'  Introduction    to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science  '
'  to Introduction    programming is a new name for Basics of computer science  '
```

Result from unleashing the `while()` shown commented out:

```
'  Introduction    to programming is a new name for Basics of computer science  '
'  to Introduction    is programming new a for name of Basics science  computer '
```

Notice the preservation of leading and trailing spaces.

Left as an exercise would be to use `strlen()` and `malloc()` to create a buffer the same size as the initial string, then replacing the `putchar()` operations with simple assignments to that buffer, creating a complete buffer with one or more words swapped...